# Looking for alternative to using "Find" on a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that currently looks into a cell, finds a certain phrases, and increases a variable by 1.

```
For x = 1 To 1000
    Set c = Range("A" & x).Find("certain phrase", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then b = b + 1
Next
```

Are there other alternative VBA methods/properties to determining if a phrase is in a cell besides Find?

Comment: `If InStr(1, Range("A" & x), "certain phrase")>0 Then b = b + 1` or `If Range("A" & x) Like "*certain phrase*" Then b = b + 1`

Comment: Awesome.  That first one is perfect.

Comment: `Find` is much quicker though as it looping through each cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:** (case sensitive)

```
For x = 1 To 1000
    If Range("A" & x) Like "*certain phrase*" Then b = b + 1
Next
```

**Option 2:** (case sensitive)

```
For x = 1 To 1000
    If InStr(1, Range("A" & x), "certain phrase") > 0 Then b = b + 1
Next
```

**Option 3:** (case insensitive)

```
For x = 1 To 1000
    If InStr(1, Range("A" & x), "certain phrase", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then b = b + 1
Next
```